# Objective-C Class Method

Tags: objective-c, class-method

My header class looks like:

```
#import "Card.h"

@interface PlayingCard : Card

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *suit;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger rank;

+ (NSArray *) validSuits;
+ (NSUInteger) maxRank;

@end
```

And my implementation:

```
@implementation PlayingCard

+ (NSArray *) validSuits
{
    return @[@"♥︎", @"♣︎", @"♦︎", @"♠︎"];
}

+ (NSArray *) rankStrings
{
    return @[@"?", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4"];
}

- (void)setSuit:(NSString *)suit
{
    if ([[PlayingCard validSuits] containsObject:suit])
    {
        _suit = suit;
    }
}

- (NSString *)suit
{
    return _suit ? _suit : @"?"; // if suit !nil return suit, else return ? string.
}

+ (NSUInteger)maxRank
{
    return [[self rankStrings] count] - 1;
}


@end
```

So I understand that any method with a + means it's a Class method.

My question is, why must I use `[PlayingCard classMethod]` e.g. `[PlayingCard validSuits]` in the `setSuit` method whereas I can use `[self classMethod]` e.g. `[self rankStrings]` in the `maxRank` method?

I'm assuming it's something to do with the `maxRank` method being a class method whereas `setSuit` isn't. But could it be because `setSuit` is a setter?

I really don't know, I can't visualise what's going on here. I've only just started my foray into Objective-C and am coming from a Java background.

I have realised I can substitute `PlayingCard` in for `self` in the `maxRank` method without any error messages, however substituting `self` in for `PlayingCard` in the `setSuit` method gives me an error saying

```
No visible @interface for 'PlayingCard' declares the selector for 'validSuits'
```

Any explanation as to why this is the case and what's going on would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The meaning of `self` in methods**

Every Objective-C method receives an implicit `self` argument. Instance methods receive the instance, while class methods receive the class object (remember: classes are objects).

If you want to send a class method, the compiler lets you use two types of syntax:

1. `[ClassName classMethod]`
2. `[classObjectPtr classMethod]`

The first syntax is used in `[PlayingCard maxRank]`. Here, the target is (explicitly) the `PlayingCard` class.

A class method already has a class object as a target for sending class methods: the `self` argument. So they can use `[self classMethod]` to send other class methods.

**Why sending a message to `self` in class methods?**

The advantage of the latter is that the class is not explicitly named. This makes it possible to override class methods in subclasses and call them from base classes.

You basically get the same dynamic method dispatch as with instance methods. This is actually a nice feature of Objective-C not present in Java or C++.

Instance methods would use the dynamic version by accessing their class and sending the message to that:

```
- (void)setSuit:(NSString *)suit
{
    if ([[[self class] validSuits] containsObject:suit])
    {
        _suit = suit;
    }
}
```

Now an imaginary subclass of `PlayingCard` could override the class method `validSuits` and implicitly alter the behavior of `setSuit:`.

Answer (score 0):

`self` can be an instance or a class depending on the type of method declared.

`- (void)setSuit:` is an instance method, thus `self` is an instance inside this method declaration.

`+ (NSUInteger)maxRank` is a class method, thus `self` is a class inside inside this method declaration.

```
+ (void)classMethod;

- (void)instanceMethod;

- (void)setSuit
{   // self is an instance here
    [self classMethod]; // warning, class method sent to instance
    [self instanceMethod]; // works, instance method sent to instance
}

+ (NSUInteger)maxRank
{   // self is a class here
    [self classMethod]; // works, class method sent to class
    [self instanceMethod]; // warning, instance method sent to class
}
```

You tried to called a "class method" on `self` inside an instance method where `self` in an "instance".

Comment: In your last sentence you're saying that `self` is an instance variable. You're probably mixing up "instance" and "instance variable" (== ivar) which means something else in Objective-C.

Comment: Cheers, Michael. It makes sense now!

Answer (score -1):

In a class method, `self` refers to the class (it refers to an object that represents the class that obj-c runtime creates for you), so you can use it to call class level method.

In an instance method, `self` refers to the instance. If you want to call class level method in an instance method, you need to use the class name instead.

Java analogy of obj-c class methods is the static method. Java's `this` keyword is similar to `self`, except it can't be used to refer to a class.

Comment: Thanks, David. Clear and concise! Appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

`setSuit` is an instance method, and `validSuits` is a class method. However, both `maxRank` and `rankStrings` are class methods. Class methods are basically the same as static methods in C++

Comment: With one big difference: static methods in C++ do not have an implicit `this` reference, while class methods in Objective-C do (and `self` is a reference to the class).